# why does createElement prevent the DOM from loading in react-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm going through this [tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers), and was fine until I changed the Records component and added `React.createElement RecordForm, handleNewRecord: @addRecord` between two DOM renderings. Seems to interfere and prevent the DOM from rendering at all.

Here's the component:

```
@Records = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    records: @props.data
  getDefaultProps: ->
    records: []
  addRecord: (record) ->
    records = @state.records.slice()
    records.push record
    @setState records: records
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: 'records'
      React.DOM.h2
        className: 'title'
        'Records'
      React.createElement RecordForm, handleNewRecord: @addRecord
      React.DOM.hr null
      React.DOM.table
        className: 'table table-bordered'
        React.DOM.thead null,
          React.DOM.tr null,
            React.DOM.th null, 'Date'
            React.DOM.th null, 'Title'
            React.DOM.th null, 'Amount'
        React.DOM.tbody null,
          for record in @state.records
            React.createElement Record, key: record.id, record: record
```

Console error says "Uncaught ReferenceError: RecordForm is not defined". Which, yes I do, and it's:

```
@RecordForm = React.createClass
 bla bla bla bla
 handleChange: (e) ->
   name = e.target.name
   @setState "#{ name }": e.target.value
 handleSubmit: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.post '', { record: @state }, (data) =>
      @props.handleNewRecord data
      @setState @getInitialState()
    , 'JSON'
  render: ->
    React.DOM.form
     bla bla bla bla
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had an unintended space before handleChange. Adding newlines between each function solved it. >:/